# How do I get Net Use to map full dfs path to folder and not truncate when using /home flag

Tags: windows-10, net-use, dfs

When executing the command:

> `NET USE H: \\fully.qualified.name\dfs\path\to\folder /home`,

Windows 10 will only map **H:** to **\\full.unc.name\dfs**

When adding the **/home** designation, the path gets truncated.  Drop **/home** and the full path gets mapped.

Answer (score 0):

[How the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11)) [is written](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html), it doesn't appear you can map network path to a drive letter AND make it *home* at the same time (in one command). You can just do it in two different commands/lines:

```
NET USE H: \\fully.qualified.name\dfs\path\to\folder
NET USE H: /home
```